# Different bootstrap CSS files?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I downloaded a Web template which is based on bootstrap version 3.

Inside the template I found CSS files named `bootstrap-cerulean.css, bootstrap-journal.css, bootstrap-classis.css`. Although, I can not find a file named `bootstrap.css`. What do `bootstrap-cerulean.css, bootstrap-journal & bootstrap-classis` define or do? Are they themes for bootstrap? Do I still need to reference `bootstrap.css` if I reference one of the themes such as `bootstrap-cerulean.css`?

Comment: The idea of simply [googling “bootstrap cerulean”](https://www.google.com/search?q=bootstrap+cerulean) did not occur to you …?

Comment: @CBroe so it is a theme for bootstrap.css, and there is no need to reference bootstrap.css if i am already referencing bootstrap-cerulean.css ? is this correct ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the bootstrap.css styles are most probably modified and integrated with those three mentioned custom css files that you got with the template so no, you don't need to link the default bootstrap.css anymore unless you're planning to override certain elements on the page to the default style (which I would recommend using a new css file with the few changes kept there for overriding the template's style rather than linking the whole bootstrap.css to the template.