# Why is there so much css files in bootstra v4? Should I include only bootstrap.css?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I'm new to Bootstrap and so far I've worked only with v3.

Today I decided to check v4 and found so much css files there.

> boostrap.css
>
> boostrap.min.css
>
> boostrap-grid.css
>
> boostrap-grid.min.css
>
> boostrap-reboot.css
>
> boostrap-reboot.min.css

**What are these new files used for?**

**Should I include only bootstrap.min.css if I don't want to edit any css files?**

I'm afraid that something might now work if I don't include some of the new css files.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Different bootstrap CSS files?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29088177/different-bootstrap-css-files)

Answer (score 0):

The .min.css files are "minified" versions of the files of the same name. It simply means all extra tabs and spacing have been removed from those.

Typically, including just bootstrap.min.css (or bootstrap.css) will import all other needed files, making it unnecessary to link the other stylesheets.

Comment: should I put all the files from the folder in my projects, but just link bootstrap.min.css and bootstrap.min.js ?

Comment: It may be best to use a CDN, since bootstrap provides this for free, and if a user has visited a site with the same bootstrap version, it will likely already be cached for them.

https://www.bootstrapcdn.com/